# Github API is returning nothing on localhost, settings missing?

Tags: php, api, github

for a project in PHP I've been wanting to add issues to a Github project based on the feedback provided by users. However, I get stuck just getting something from the Github API. The following command line gives me the info I expect to get:

```
$ curl -u <username> https://api.github.com/user
```

This gives me my user info, but when I try in PHP i just get black pages. My code is:

```
<?php
$ch     = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.github.com/user' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "<username>:<password>" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
$output = curl_exec( $ch );
$info   = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $output;
var_dump( $info );
?>
```

Where I suspect the $output to be the same as what I got with the command line, but here it's blank. What I do get is the $info:

```
array(26) { ["url"]=> string(27) "https://api.github.com/user" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.203) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.015) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.109) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(14) "192.30.252.136" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=> int(443) ["local_ip"]=> string(13) "192.168.0.109" ["local_port"]=> int(28935) }
```

I couldn't find any simple example to use in PHP, and I don't want to use an entire framework for something that should be so simple. From what I get from the API documentation I should be able to send my credentials and then get the info.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but can't figure it out, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I kept looking and found [this](https://github.com/macuenca/Instagram-PHP-API/issues/8) issue. It appears curl returns empty for https when working locally unless I inlcude 

`curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );`

After that, I got the message I was missing a user agent, and after including that it worked. Hope I helped someone else with this.

Comment: Please consider submitting this as an answer to your own question, and then accepting it. That way others will have a better chance of learning from your work.

Comment: I will, I couldnt before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept looking and found [this](https://github.com/macuenca/Instagram-PHP-API/issues/8) issue on the github project of another API. It appears the curl indeed returns empty for https in combination with working locally unless I inlcude

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
```

After that, I got the message I was missing a user agent, and after including this it worked. After uploading the original code to my webhosting it I get the missing user agent message in the first place.

Hope I can help someone else with this.